# Fill a grid with empty rectangles in D3.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to create a calender (24 hours, 7 weekdays), that displays certain data points for each hour. As I don't have data for every hour (and thus don't want to leave the rest blank), I would like to prefill the grid with empty rectangles.

The problem I have is that I know how to approach this by first creating an empty Object (so for each weekday we create 24 data points, leading to a total of 7 * 24). But this is a rather inefficient way in my opinion and it slows down the website since we first have to create the empty Object.

Here is the current code:

```
var test = svg.selectAll(".time")
    .data(emptyarray)
    .enter().append("rect")
    .attr("x", function(d) { return (d.time) * gridSize; })
    .attr("y", function(d) { return (d.weekday) * gridSize; })
    .attr("rx", 4)
    .attr("ry", 4)
    .attr("class", "bordered")
    .attr("width", gridSize)
    .attr("height", gridSize)
    .style("fill", colors[0]);
```

I have tried several solutions, namely a few for-loop constructs but that lead to the problem that it only displayed 1 rectangle at a certain position, instead of filling the entire grid with rectangles. Any suggestions on how to approach this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm going to play around with solutions today if I can. My current thinking is to create an array, fill it with 7 * 24 datapoints using d3.range() and then bind your data to that array. I'm also thinking that the most efficient way to do this is on the back-end and then send the prepared object to your javascript using an API...

Comment: Creating all the objects up front is the way to go in D3. 24 * 7 = 168, which is really not a large number.

Answer (score 0):

How about simply filtering `emptyarray` prior to drawing?
For example

```
var test = svg.selectAll(".time")
    .data(emptyarray.filter(function(d){ return d !== undefined; }))
    .enter().append("rect")
    .attr("x", function(d) { return (d.time) * gridSize; })
    .attr("y", function(d) { return (d.weekday) * gridSize; })
    .attr("rx", 4)
    .attr("ry", 4)
    .attr("class", "bordered")
    .attr("width", gridSize)
    .attr("height", gridSize)
    .style("fill", "green");
```

If you want empty rectangles (An empty `<rect>` in the SVG DOM is far more wasteful of resources than an empty javascript object), you could:

```
var test = svg.selectAll(".time")
    .data(emptyarray)
    .enter().append("rect")
    .attr("x", function(d, i) { 
        return d === undefined ? i*gridSize : (d.time) * gridSize; 
    })
    .attr("y", function(d, i) { 
        return d === undefined ? i*gridSize : (d.weekday) * gridSize; 
    })
    .attr("rx", 4)
    .attr("ry", 4)
    .attr("class", function(d){ 
        return d === undefined ? "invisible": "bordered"; 
    })
    .attr("width", gridSize)
    .attr("height", gridSize)
    .style("fill", "green");
```

Add the css

```
.invisible{
        visibility: hidden;
}
```

If you haven't already, I'd recommend reading the [D3 time scale documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Scales). You might consider a scale to map from time to pixel location, eg.

```
var x = d3.time.scale()
    .range([0, width]);
```

and also `d3.time.week` etc. which can neatly "round" dates to the nearest interval (eg. week).